# update the table using same table

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I want to update rows of scenario_id=1 from scenario_id=7 where name matches. The difference between scenario_id is not constant.

```
id|scenario_id|status|name
1 |1          |Passed|testcase_1
2 |1          |Passed|testcase_2
3 |1          |Failed|willPassInNextRun
4 |7          |Passed|testcase_1
5 |7          |Passed|willPassInNextRun
```

after the update table should look like below

```
id|scenario_id|status|name
1 |1          |Passed|testcase_1
2 |1          |Passed|testcase_2
3 |1          |Passed|willPassInNextRun
4 |7          |Passed|testcase_1
5 |7          |Passed|willPassInNextRun
```

Comment: What is the result you want ? Because I am not sure to understand.

Comment: Can you write a SELECT query that returns the correct result?

Comment: *What* should be updated? How should the table look afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work also in SQLite, use standard SQL and look up the new value with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET status = COALESCE((SELECT status
                       FROM MyTable AS T2
                       WHERE scenario_id = 7
                         AND T2.name = MyTable.name),
                      status)
WHERE scenario_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
update table t1, table t2
 set t1.status=t2.status
 where t2.scenario_id=7 and t1.scenario_id=1
 and t1.name=t2.name
 and t1.status!=t2.status;
```